# Cannot be resolved to a type - Error while compiling servlet (tomcat) on RHEL 5

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

I am using RHEL 5 with apache-tomcat-6.0.37.
Database is MySQL and i am using mysql-connector-java-3.2.0-alpha for connectivity.

I am getting these error while compiling my java servlets.

These servlets were working fine in my college but when i tried to run it on my home computer it gave me these error.

It can be a configurational issue.
I had setup class path in .bashrc file however its not working.So i tried to execute it using below command.

```
[root@localhost classes]# javac fbLoginServlet.java -classpath /root/apache-tomcat-    6.0.37/lib/servlet-api.jar
----------
1. WARNING in fbLoginServlet.java (at line 5)
public class fbLoginServlet extends HttpServlet
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The serializable class fbLoginServlet does not declare a static final serialVersionUID     field of type long
----------
2. ERROR in fbLoginServlet.java (at line 12)
    UserDAO udao=new UserDAO();
    ^^^^^^^
UserDAO cannot be resolved to a type
----------
3. ERROR in fbLoginServlet.java (at line 12)
    UserDAO udao=new UserDAO();
                     ^^^^^^^
UserDAO cannot be resolved to a type
----------
4. ERROR in fbLoginServlet.java (at line 13)
    UserVO uvo=new UserVO();
    ^^^^^^
```

Here is my .bashrc file.

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45
export CATALINA_HOME=/root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-3.2.0-alpha-bin.jar
```

Please let me know if you any more details.

Comment: You need to specify the `.class` files for `UserDao`, `UserVo`, etc. in the classpath.

Comment: The problem with the `UserDAO` class, it does not exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but i am already specifying it in the web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at

```
javac fbLoginServlet.java -classpath /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

you are compiling the `fbLoginServlet` class without the `UserDAO` and `UserVO` classes. Change your classpath to

```
javac fbLoginServlet.java -classpath /folder/containing/those/classes:/root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

Where `/folder/containing/those/classes` is the folder that contains the packages containing the missing classes.